# TypeError: Select is not a constructor when using Svelte and jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, svelte, testing-library

When writing a Jest test for a Svelte component I am getting a `TypeError: Select is not a constructor` error when the component imports a library using the es6 import syntax.

TestSelect.js:

```js
<script>
  import Select from 'svelte-select';

  let items = [
    {value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate'},
    {value: 'pizza', label: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'cake', label: 'Cake'},
    {value: 'chips', label: 'Chips'},
    {value: 'ice-cream', label: 'Ice Cream'},
  ];
  
  let selectedValue = undefined;
</script>

<Select {items} bind:selectedValue></Select>
```

TestSelect.spec.js:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';

import TestSelect from './TestSelect.svelte';


describe('Component', () => {
  test('Should render', () => {
    const { container } = render(TestSelect, {});
    expect(true);
  });
});
```

Jest config

```js
 "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.svelte$": "svelte-jester"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "svelte"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
    ],
    "verbose": true
  }
```

I'm wondering if there is a jest config option that I have missed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you try with [jest-transform-svelte](https://github.com/rspieker/jest-transform-svelte). By the way, you can replace `render(TestSelect, {})` with `render(TestSelect)`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @johannchopin I have tried that and unfortunately I get the same error

Comment: If you look into the package you can see that the exported file is a `.svelte`. By default jest ignore the `node_modules`. So the `'svelte-select'` package will not be compiled before testing. Would be easier that the author provide the compiled component directly

Comment: thanks @johannchopin that is definitely the problem as the test runs fine when I import the file from a location outside of the node_modules folder. Having a problem excluding the node module using the jest transformIgnorePatterns value but I guess that is another question! Thanks again

Comment: No problem I had the same issue with a svelte library that just export the svelte component. Not sure why so many people do it this way.

Comment: Struggling about the same problem. Using svelte-generic-table-pager. @johannchopin do you have a link/handout/example for a proper e.g. index.js. How to handle the default export in svelte/customElement? Any help wanted :) This question is still unsolved. A folder outside node_modules did not work. Can you answer? best

Answer (score 4):

So the main problem with Jest, is that by default it ignore all files in the `node_folder`. So when Jest see imported Svelte libraries in your code it doesn't compile them before running the test which cause errors.

An solution would be to tell jest to not ignore the `svelte-select` library by adding this in the jest config:

```js
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(svelte-select)/)' /* ignore node_module but not node_modules/svelte-select/* */
  ],
```

Another issue with the library itself, is that the default exported element is not a Svelte component but a precompiled simple `.js` file as you see [here](https://github.com/rob-balfre/svelte-select/blob/master/package.json#L8). This file is not understand by jest and cause your error:

> TypeError: Select is not a constructor

The library export the Svelte component in the [Select.js](https://github.com/rob-balfre/svelte-select/blob/master/Select.js) file. This one is valid to be understand by your application and jest.

So to fix your issue, you should import this component using:

```js
import Select from 'svelte-select/Select';
```

Like that, jest will understand that it imports a `.svelte` file and should compile it using the `svelte-jester` transformer.

Ideally you can ask the author of the library to export by default the Svelte component using in `package.json`:

```json
 "main": "Select.js",
```

I've created a repo to show you the working configuration: https://github.com/johannchopin/test-svelte-component-in-node_module.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around this problem by using rollup to bundle my tests first and then run jest on the bundled output. A similar way is described in [this blog post](https://dev.to/d_ir/setting-up-a-svelte-test-environment-2f3e).

Comment: Please avoid link only answer and try to explain a little what this post is about.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue. I am using Typescript for my svelte APP.

```
// TestSelect.js:
import Select from 'svelte-select/Select';
```

Jest config file

```
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.svelte$": [
        "svelte-jester",
        {
          "preprocess": true
        }
      ],
      "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "ts",
      "svelte"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(svelte-select))"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "cypress"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".css": "<rootDir>/empty-module.js",
      "intl-tel-input": "<rootDir>/user-intl-module.js"
    }
  }
```