# TypeError: Component is not a constructor when testing Svelte Component

Tags: javascript, jestjs, svelte, svelte-3

I want to use [svelte-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/svelte-testing-library) and [svelte-htm](https://github.com/kenoxa/svelte-htm) to test the two way binding of a property passed to a custom Svelte component. When trying to render the component during the test, this exception is thrown:

```
TypeError: Component is not a constructor

   9 | it("should generate first page", async () => {
  10 |   let pageRows = writable([]);
> 11 |   const { getByRole } = render(
     |                         ^
  12 |     html`<${Pagination} rows=${[1, 2, 3]} bind:pageRows=${pageRows} />`
  13 |   );
  14 |   const button = getByRole("div");

  at create_fragment (node_modules/svelte-hyperscript/src/h.js:132:21)
  at Object.init (node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1454:37)
  at new Component (node_modules/svelte-hyperscript/src/h.js:78:7)
  at render (node_modules/@testing-library/svelte/dist/pure.js:71:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (Pagination.test.js:11:25)
```

I made a codesandbox to reproduce the issue. I wasn't able to run the test in codesandbox at all but you can download the code as zip and then do `npm install && npm run test`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-snyder-1k8g0?file=/Pagination.test.js

Comment: Duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/q/63504725/8583669. Issue is that the `svelte-htm` export `.svelte` components directly without building them. So jest don't know how to compile a `.svelte`. You will need to tell to jest to first compile them.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I tell jest to compile them? I already tried `transformIgnorePatterns: []` and added "node_modules" to `moduleDirectories` and `modulePaths` in my `jest.config.js`.